What causes bands to shift in energy or become narrow?
This is the density of states for pure palladium in bulk : 
This is the density of states of palladium hydride :

clearly the d bands are shifting and becoming narrow. The narrowing of bands is said to be a consequence of depletion of states. But states cant simply vanish, they can only redistribute by combining with other states (bonding and anti bonding). So if the states are depleting, where are they going to ? Also how is this shifting happening ? If two levels of the same energy were to combine, one would go down and the other up, so how is this unidirectional shifting happening ?
This is an MO diagram I have found for palladium hydride and I am unable to correlate it with the DOS :

